# how to add lambda condition to linq

Tags: linq

I have this condition:

```
Expression<Func<LoginTable, bool>> seleWhere
```

and want to  add this condition into above linq:

```
 from a in DataContext.Set<LoginTable>()
 where 【condition】
 select a
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that using the blue syntax but you can write it the normal way like this:

```
DataContext.Set<LoginTable>().Where(seleWhere)
```

Comment: i know this way ,but why cannot

Comment: The `from where select` syntax is only a simplification, convenient way of writing simple queries and it's translated into the normal syntax anyway. And you can use only explicit conditions there it is because it was designed that way. More over the `Expression` stuff makes another layer of complexity as your query is translated to sql rather then executed.

Comment: There is a way to do this but it is very complicated. Basically the compiler does not help you with it (I also think it should). However, if you really want to do this, you can use LINQKit and it will make this possible.